# Make URLs unique based on their domain name

Tags: bash, awk, unique

I have a list of URLs named **urls.list**:

```
https://target.com/?first=one
https://target.com/something/?first=one
http://target.com/dir/?first=summer
https://fake.com/?first=spring
https://example.com/about/?third=three
https://example.com/?third=three
```

and I want to make them unique based on their domains like `https://target.com`, That means each domain with its protocol prints once and the next URLs are avoided.
so the result would be:

```
https://target.com/?first=one
http://target.com/dir/?first=summer
https://fake.com/?first=spring
https://example.com/about/?third=three
```

This is what I tried to do:

```
cat urls.list | cut -d"/" -f1-3 | awk '!a[$0]++' >> host_unique.del

for urls in $(cat urls.list); do

    for hosts in $(cat host_unique.del); do
        if [[ $hosts == *"$urls"* ]]; then
            echo "$hosts"
        fi
    done
done
```

Comment: Tangentially, [don't read lines with `for`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor) and avoid the [useless use of `cat`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710552/useless-use-of-cat)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This `awk` might do what you wanted.

```
awk -F'/' '!seen[$1,$3]++' urls.list
```

---

A bash alternative would be very slow on large set of data/files but here it is.

Using `mapfile` aka `readarray` which is a bash4+ feature, associative array. plus some more bash features.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

declare -A uniq
mapfile -t urls < urls.list

for uniq_url in "${urls[@]}"; do
  IFS='/' read -ra url <<< "$uniq_url"
  if ((!uniq["${url[0]}","${url[2]}"]++)); then
    printf '%s\n' "$uniq_url"
  fi
done
```

Answer (score 2):

With your shown samples, please try following.

```
awk 'match($0,/https?:\/\/[^/]*/){val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)} !arr[val]++' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                               ##Starting awk program from here.
match($0,/https?:\/\/[^/]*/){       ##using match to match http or https followedby ://
  val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)     ##Creating val which has matched string value here.
}
!arr[val]++                         ##Checking condition if val not present in arr then print current line.
' Input_file                        ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: What does **?** do after https ?

Comment: @sof31, its like match http OR https, it means keeping `?` as optional so it will match http OR https here.